# Are "mist" and "missed" really pronounced exactly the same in English?

Tags: pronunciation

Refer the section called "Pronunciation Features" in this [page](http://www.pbs.org/speak/education/curriculum/high/aae/). In that section, you can find this sentence "Interestingly, mist and missed are pronounced exactly the same in English". Really? I don't pronounce both of them the same way.

- Mist - I pronounce this as "mĭst"
- Missed - I pronounce this as "mĭsd"

Am I wrong? Should I pronounce both of them exactly the same?

Comment: Now I'm curious -- what is your native language?

Comment: @leoger My native language is Tamil.

Comment: They are not only pronounced identically; until English orthography stabilized in the late 17th century they were often spelled identically: OED reports *miste*, *mist*, and *myst* for both.

Comment: I'm unable to even *imagine* how "misd" could sound, if not exactly the same as "mist". I tried for a while to pronounce "misd" differently but it made the "s" sound like a "z", or the "d" sound like a "der" (as in, "mister"), which certainly did not sound like the word "missed" any more!

Comment: @Boann - The only way I could make them sound differently was to make them, in effect, two-syllable words, pronounced like _miss·tə_ and _miss·də_.

Comment: In my Hiberno-English these words would have a subtle difference, which one could emphasise for clarity. In missed one actually pronounces the 'd' with a "duh" rather than "tuh".

Comment: Yes, I'm from England and I would say both in exactly the same way.

Comment: In fact it varies throughout the United Kingdom depending on how well the local dialect enunciates the hardness of the final 'ed' compared with the final 't'. In Scotland 'mist' is often 'Dreich', a Gaelic word for a depressing wetness that seeps through to your bones ;-)

Comment: @J.R. As Italian *that* would be the *natural* way to pronounce them. And that's how in fact I *do* pronounce them if I speak without much attention on the pronunciation.

Comment: And from the US (from Chicago, IL), I pronounce them the same.  They have such different meanings that I can't imagine one being confused for the other when used in a sentence.

Comment: @Izkata - While one being confused with the other may be unlikely for _mist_ and _missed_, there are other, similar word pairs where it may not always be so clear cut, such as _rapt_ and _rapped_, _bussed_ and _bust_, _guessed_ and _guest_, _massed_ and _mast_, or _blessed_ and _blest_.

Comment: I found this video very helpful http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7hi-ipU2n0

Comment: At least in my mid-western (Ohio) dialect of American English there's no pronunciation difference between these two words.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The suffix *-ed* is typically pronounced in one of three ways:

- /d/ after voiced sounds other than /d/.
- /t/ after voiceless sounds other than /t/.
- /ɪd/ after /t/ or /d/.

The verb *miss* is pronounced /mɪs/.  Since the final sound is the voiceless consonant /s/, the suffix *-ed* is pronounced /t/.  This means that the whole word *missed* is pronounced /mɪst/.

Coincidentally, the noun *mist* is also pronounced /mɪst/.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that after 12 years of pronouncing it "misd" :(

Comment: @almousawi - I'd like to hear how that sounds different from "mist".

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7hi-ipU2n0

Comment: One might expand this to say that any English word ending in the _sd_ sound will sound the same as if it ended with the _st_ sound.

Answer (score 8):

In words that end with *t* or *ed*, the key is the **preceding consonant sound**. Some letters blend with the *t* and *d* so that the sounds are distinguishable, but some don't.

For example:

- the *f* sound causes the *-ed* to sound like a *t*: that's why *stiffed* rhymes with *lift*
- the *k* sound caused the *-ed* to sound like a *t*: that's why *backed* rhymes with *fact*
- the *p* sound caused the *-ed* to sound like a *t*: that's why *wrapped* rhymes with *apt*
- the *s* sound caused the *-ed* to sound like a *t*: that's why *kissed* rhymes with *list*

However:

- *-ed* and *t* sound different after *l*, which is why *felled* and *belt* do not rhyme
- *-ed* and *t* sound different after *r*, which is why *barred* and *cart* do not rhyme
- *-ed* and *t* sound different after *n*, which is why *panned* and *rant* do not rhyme

These aren't deliberate "rules" that need to be remembered; these are simply ways the sounds come out naturally. (It's worth paying attention to how similarly we pronounce some pairs of consonants, such as *b* and *p*, or *t* and *d*. Simply pronounce each one three or four times, and pay attention to how similarly your lips and tongue move.)

Some consonants don't figure into this discussion, because there aren't any words that end with sounds like:

- *gt* (to compare with, say, *hugged*)
- *bt* (to compare with, say, *ribbed*)

Comment: Found this very helpful: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7hi-ipU2n0

Comment: It may be worth noting that "used" has two different pronunciations depending upon whether it's actually serving as a verb, or as part of an idiomatic expression relating previous behavior.  A sentence like "There's the desk I used to study" could have two meanings which would for a native speaker be readily discernible by pronunciation [was had the person previously been studying the desk itself, or utilizing the desk to facilitate the study of other things]?

Answer (score 7):

It's probably not fair to say you've been doing it "wrong" -- you would be understood by a slightly surprised listener -- but you haven't been doing it right if your goal is to sound native.

In every dialect of English I know, a native speaker would have an almost impossibly hard time even making the sound "mĭsd". (Possibly with the exception of some regions of India.) It took me **three minutes** of trying and now my neck hurts because I have to really use untrained muscles to stop the air before I turn on my voice to make a 't' into a 'd'.

[Edit] Other answers on this question have done a great job of explaining the rules. I've learned something myself!

Comment: Really? I never know this. Where is the proof? I search missed in many dictionaries, but they show only how to pronounce "miss". I don't see a dictionary which  shows the pronunciation of "missed". I don't understand how one can pronounce 't' as 'd'? Is there any other example like?  Do you pronounce the 't' in 'mist' and 'ed' in 'missed' as 't' in 'tea'?

Comment: I don't know if this is "proof", but its some evidence: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/missed#Pronunciation

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of "voice" in phonetics? The only difference between /t/ and /d/ is whether your vocal cords are moving. Your tongue and lips are doing the exact same thing, right? So, the *reason* that something can be written as a 'd' and pronounced as a /t/ is because there is a close relationship between these sounds. As for whether I say it the same as in 'tea', I couldn't tell you because English only has one kind of /t/ sound, so my ear is not used to understanding different *kinds* of /t/. The difference *does* exist in Tamil, though.

Comment: Oh! So I've been pronouncing all of these words 'called', "attacked", "Killed", "Filled", "pulled" wrongly? I pronounce all of these words with the ending sound "d".

Comment: Well, I just learned that Tamil does not make a distinction between voiced and unvoiced consonants. I don't think I ever knew of a language with such a characteristic, before. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_phonology)

Comment: How do you the difference does exist in Tamil? Do you know Tamil? Are you Tamilian?

Comment: I don't know what is mean by voiced and unvoiced consonants. I don't understand it clearly by reading in wiki. I'll go and check some youtube videos to understand it.

Comment: @T2E, I'm honestly not sure if you've been pronouncing them wrong. You may just *think* you are pronouncing them wrong. Or, it's possible that you are making two sounds that *you* can hear the difference between but that most English speakers cannot. This video might help explain voiced/voiceless consonants: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pqe_HJVpUv0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13053/discussion-between-leoger-and-t2e)

Comment: I checked few videos, and now I understood the difference between voiced and unvoiced consonants. I don't know the term for these, but I'm familiar these. I do pronounce "d" and "t" differently. I pronounce "dog" and "tea" correctly, where "d" is voiced and "t" is unvoiced, but I always pronounced "missed", "called", filled", "pulled"  and even "unvoiced" with ending voiced sound of "d". So you are saying all of these words are pronounced with "unvoiced" end sound of "t" or only "missed" is pronounced in that way?

Comment: Careful here; _killed_ is **not** a homophone of _kilt_, nor is _felled_ pronounced the same as _felt_. The words _burned_ and _burnt_ are not pronounced the same, either. But _missed_ and _mist_ are. The key is the sound _before_ the "t" and "d". Some letters blend with these such that the sounds are distinguishable (like "n", as in _panned_ and _pant_, or "r", as in _card_ and _cart_), but some don't (like "s", as in _missed_ and _mist_, or "f", as in the rhyming _stiffed_ and _lift_).

Comment: @T2E See snailplane's answer for the rules. *Called*, *killed*, &c are pronounced with /d/, because /l/ is voiced; *attacked* and *missed* are pronounced with /t/ because /k/ and /s/ are voiceless.

Comment: @J.R. Okay. But in this situation as a non-native English speaker how I would I differentiate any two words are homophone or not just by looking at the spelling? All of the words I mentioned ends with "ed". There is no grammar rule that a non native English can use to understand?

Comment: If there are rules, they are not taught to us natives. Simply put, that's just the way the sounds come out naturally, without even thinking about it. We don't TRY to pronounce _missed_ with a _t_ sound at the end; it just comes out that way when we say the word. As others have said, it's hard to hard to pronounce _bust_ and _bussed_ as two different-sounding words. If you can do it, you have quite a talent there.

Comment: @J.R. there is a simple rule, namely, the one described in snailplane's answer. The reason it seems natural to you and you didn't have to learn it is that you are a native speaker. It is in fact not easy or natural for all non native speakers to notice and copy this pattern without being explicitly told about it, as is evinced by the fact that OP has been saying it wrong for 11 years without realizing it.

Comment: For what it's worth, in some ("non-standard") dialects, _killed_ **is** pronounced "kilt" and _called_ pronounced "calt", and so on.

Comment: @hunter - If the O.P. has been saying the two words in a way such that they are distinguishable one from the other, I wouldn't say that the word _missed_ has been pronounced "wrong". If one can enunciate _missed_ so that it sounds like it ends with a _d_ instead of a _t_, I wouldn't call that an incorrect pronunciation.

Comment: @leoger - how do you deal with saying "misdiagnosed"? Do you leave a long gap between mis- and diagnosed?

Comment: @DanialEarwicker The discussion is about a consonant cluster which closes a syllable. In *misdiagnosed* this is not the case; the first syllable is closed by the /s/ and the /d/ starts the next syllable. The voicing 'on' the /d/ is therefore implicated in the following vowel /ai/ (or whatever vowel the speaker's dialect employs for this phoneme) and there's no problem.

Comment: @StoneyB: Thanks for that! It makes so much sense now. I'll update my answer to reflect some of what has been said on this long chain of comments...

Comment: @StoneyB: Interesting! The implication is that *misd* comes out as *misduh* whereas *mist* **doesn't** turn into *mistuh*. But if I try to make the shortest, most percussive *d* sound I can, it always has a bit of *duh* to it, and consequently my pronunciation of *misd* sounds "good enough" to my (untrained) ears.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: There really is NO difference between the /t/ and the /d/ themselves; it's all in the quality of the sounds before and after. A voiced sound before or after the stop extends its voicing slightly to distinguish /d/, but a voiceless sound has no voicing to extend. That's why you never encounter terminal /sd/ in English.